# Sorting Users page admin column with ACF field

Tags: users, advanced-custom-fields, sort, columns

I have a CPT called **Companies**. I created an ACF relationship field called **user_company** that gets displayed in the Users profile page.

When a user registers, I have to go in and assign them to a company. I added the ACF field to the Users page admin column but I am unable to sort it. It currently sorts based on post_id and I have no idea how to sort it by post_title.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
// Add columns and data to Users admin page
add_filter( 'manage_users_columns', 'manage_users_columns_new_columns' );
function manage_users_columns_new_columns( $columns ) {
    $columns['user_comp any'] = 'User Company';
  return $columns;
}
add_filter( 'manage_users_custom_column', 'manage_users_custom_column_new_columns', 10, 3 );
function manage_users_custom_column_new_columns( $value, $column_name, $user_id ) {
    if ( $column_name == 'user_company' ) {
        $user_company = get_field('user_company', 'user_' . $user_id);
        $user_company_post = get_post($user_company);
        if( isset( $user_company_post ) ){
          return $user_company_post->post_title;
        } else {
          return '-';
        }
    }
    return $value;
}

// ACF/save_post to save title of User Company as another meta_value
function save_user_company_name ( $post_id ) {
  $user_company_id = get_field( 'user_company', $post_id );
  if ( $user_company_id ) {
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'user_company_name', get_post_field( 'post_title', $user_company_id ) );
  }
}
add_action( 'acf/save_post', 'save_user_company_name', 20 );

// Sort columns on Users admin page
add_filter( 'manage_users_sortable_columns', 'register_sortable_columns_custom', 10, 1 );
function register_sortable_columns_custom( $columns ) {
    $columns['user_company'] = 'user_company';
  return $columns;
}
add_action( 'pre_get_users', 'pre_get_users_sort_columns_custom' );
function pre_get_users_sort_columns_custom( $query ) {
    if ( $query->get( 'orderby' ) == 'user_company' ) { // Currently sorts by post ID vs post title. Will need to add additional code: https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/admin-column-a-z-sorting-for-object-field/
        $query->set( 'orderby',  'meta_value' );
        $query->set( 'meta_key', 'user_company_name' );
  }

}
```

I added the acf/save_post portion based on answers I have found online but I don't know how that works. I tried saving each Company posts as well as the Users assigned to a company. But when I try to sort on the admin page, everything blanks out. I'm not sure how to get this to work.

Here is my updated code, still doesn't work:

```
// Add columns and data to Users admin page
add_filter( 'manage_users_columns', 'manage_users_columns_new_columns' );
function manage_users_columns_new_columns( $columns ) {
  $columns['user_organization'] = __( 'Organization', 'ultimate-member' );
  $columns['user_role'] = __( 'Organization Role', 'ultimate-member' );
    $columns['user_company'] = 'User Company';
    $columns['registration_date'] = 'Registration Date';
  return $columns;
}
add_filter( 'manage_users_custom_column', 'manage_users_custom_column_new_columns', 10, 3 );
function manage_users_custom_column_new_columns( $value, $column_name, $user_id ) {
    if ( $column_name == 'user_organization' ) {
    um_fetch_user( $user_id );
    $value = um_user( 'user_organization' );
    if( empty( $value )) {
        $value = '-';
    }
    }
    if ( $column_name == 'user_role' ) {
    um_fetch_user( $user_id );
    $value = um_user( 'user_role' );
    if( empty( $value )) {
        $value = '-';
    }
    }
    if ( $column_name == 'user_company' ) {
        $user_company = get_field('user_company', 'user_' . $user_id);
        $user_company_post = get_post($user_company);
        if( isset( $user_company_post ) ){
          return $user_company_post->post_title;
        } else {
          return '-';
        }
    }
    if ( $column_name == 'registration_date' ) {
        $date_format = 'M j, Y';
    $value = date( $date_format, strtotime( get_the_author_meta( 'registered', $user_id ) ) );
    if( empty( $value )) {
        $value = '-';
    }
    }
    return $value;
}

// Sort columns on Users admin page
add_filter( 'manage_users_sortable_columns', 'register_sortable_columns_custom', 10, 1 );
function register_sortable_columns_custom( $columns ) {
  $columns['user_organization'] = 'user_organization';
  $columns['user_role'] = 'user_role';
    $columns['user_company'] = 'user_company';
    $columns['account_status'] = 'account_status';
    $columns['registration_date'] = 'registered';
  return $columns;
}
add_action( 'pre_get_users', 'pre_get_users_sort_columns_custom' );
function pre_get_users_sort_columns_custom( $query ) {
  if ( $query->get( 'orderby' ) == 'user_organization' ) {
        $query->set( 'orderby',  'meta_value' );
        $query->set( 'meta_key', 'user_organization' );
  }
  if ( $query->get( 'orderby' ) == 'user_role' ) {
        $query->set( 'orderby',  'meta_value' );
        $query->set( 'meta_key', 'user_role' );
  }
    if ( $query->get( 'orderby' ) == 'account_status' ) {
        $query->set( 'orderby',  'meta_value' );
        $query->set( 'meta_key', 'account_status' );
  }
    if ( $query->get( 'orderby' ) == 'registration_date' ) {
        $query->set( 'orderby',  'meta_value' );
        $query->set( 'meta_key', 'registered' );
  }
}

// Make ACF column on User's page sortable
if ( is_admin() ) {
    add_action('pre_user_query', 'sort_users_by_acf_company_field');
}
function sort_users_by_acf_company_field( $userquery ){
  if ( 'user_company'==$userquery->query_vars['orderby'] ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $userquery->query_from .= " LEFT OUTER JOIN $wpdb->usermeta AS alias ON ($wpdb->users.ID = alias.user_id) ";//note use of alias
    $userquery->query_where .= " AND alias.meta_key = 'user_company' ";//which meta are we sorting with?
    $userquery->query_orderby = " ORDER BY alias.meta_value ".($userquery->query_vars["order"] == "ASC" ? "asc " : "desc ");//set sort order
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "pre_user_query" filter hook to modify the query that retrieves the users.

Here's an example code that how to sort the Users page admin column with an ACF field named.

```
function sort_users_by_acf_field( $query ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() ) {
        return;
    }
    if ( isset( $query->query_vars['orderby'] ) && 'user_company_name' === $query->query_vars['orderby'] ) {
        $query->query_vars['meta_key'] = 'user_company_name';
        $query->query_vars['orderby'] = 'meta_value';
    }
}
add_action('pre_user_query','sort_users_by_acf_field');
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm still very new to hooks so not sure if I'm doing it correctly. I replaced the last action/function I have in the code above with yours and that didn't seem to do anything. It still sorts based on username.

Comment: Did you put your meta_key in my code? Can you provide more details

Comment: I did change the meta_key to user_company. Is it because the acf field is a post object and only results in a postID and that's why it can't sort by the post title? I posted the code i'm currently using in my original post above.